# Creating doubleClick code for bluetooth button

Tags: ios, swift3, click

I have received a bluetooth button which you can connect your program to, however the double click is not working for it. All the other events (up, down, click, hold) are working and calling the correct delegate.

I want somehow to manage double clicks from code.
How can I make it work, for example from the up event. (for example, if second click comes within 0.5s it behaves as a double click, if no then simple click)
this probably makes a 0.5s delay but thats acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

```
devButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(taps(_:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDownRepeat)
func taps(_ sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let t: UITouch = event.allTouches!.first!
    if (t.tapCount == 2) { devFunction() }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this is not a UIButton therefore it doesn't have addTarget.
After connected correctly, it has a delegate for click / hold / doubleClick, but the doubleClick event doesn't fire (the others are working) so I somehow need to manage it from the code with the working click or down event.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your button to the VC and add a double click listener.

```
yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doubleTapped), for: .touchDownRepeat)
```

Then handle the double click event in a function like this

```
func doubleTapped() {
    // do something cool here
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this is not a UIButton therefore it doesn't have addTarget.
After connected correctly, it has a delegate for click / hold / doubleClick, but the doubleClick event doesn't fire (the others are working) so I somehow need to manage it from the code with the working click or down event.